# Getting JSON value in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm having troubles accessing a JSON object different from the one I found in tutorial:

I have this JSON in tutorial I'm following:

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
},
"weather": [{
    "id": 803,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "broken clouds",
    "icon": "04d"
}],
"base": "cmc stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 285.325,
    "pressure": 1024.67,
    "humidity": 95,
    "temp_min": 285.325,
    "temp_max": 285.325,
    "sea_level": 1034.69,
    "grnd_level": 1024.67
},
"wind": {
    "speed": 7.46,
    "deg": 246.001
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 76
},
"dt": 1448967456,
"sys": {
    "message": 0.0027,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1448955837,
    "sunset": 1448985295
},
"id": 2643743,
"name": "London",
"cod": 200
```

}

And to get main value from it I use this code:

```
 NSURLRequest *urlrequest =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org"]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

[[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlrequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSMutableDictionary *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    NSString* currentWeather = nil;

    NSArray* weather = allData[@"weather"];

    for (NSDictionary* weatherDictionary in weather){
        currentWeather = weatherDictionary[@"main"];
    }

    [self setImageAndTextWithWeather:currentWeather];

    //NSLog(allData[@"temp_c"]);

}] resume];
```

And this is working just fine.
But now I'm trying to access to JSON object from another source which is like this:

```
  {
"response": {
    "version": "0.1",
    "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
    "features": {
        "conditions": 1
    }
},
"current_observation": {
    "image": {
        "url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title": "Weather Underground",
        "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
    },
    "display_location": {
        "full": "San Francisco, CA",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "CA",
        "state_name": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "country_iso3166": "US",
        "zip": "94101",
        "latitude": "37.77500916",
        "longitude": "-122.41825867",
        "elevation": "47.00000000"
    },
    "observation_location": {
        "full": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco, California",
        "city": "SOMA - Near Van Ness, San Francisco",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "country_iso3166": "US",
        "latitude": "37.773285",
        "longitude": "-122.417725",
        "elevation": "49 ft"
    },
    "estimated": {},
    "station_id": "KCASANFR58",
    "observation_time": "Last Updated on June 27, 5:27 PM PDT",
    "observation_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:13 -0700",
    "observation_epoch": "1340843233",
    "local_time_rfc822": "Wed, 27 Jun 2012 17:27:14 -0700",
    "local_epoch": "1340843234",
    "local_tz_short": "PDT",
    "local_tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "local_tz_offset": "-0700",
    "weather": "Partly Cloudy",
    "temperature_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
    "temp_f": 66.3,
    "temp_c": 19.1,
    "relative_humidity": "65%",
    "wind_string": "From the NNW at 22.0 MPH Gusting to 28.0 MPH",
    "wind_dir": "NNW",
    "wind_degrees": 346,
    "wind_mph": 22.0,
    "wind_gust_mph": "28.0",
    "wind_kph": 35.4,
    "wind_gust_kph": "45.1",
    "pressure_mb": "1013",
    "pressure_in": "29.93",
    "pressure_trend": "+",
    "dewpoint_string": "54 F (12 C)",
    "dewpoint_f": 54,
    "dewpoint_c": 12,
    "heat_index_string": "NA",
    "heat_index_f": "NA",
    "heat_index_c": "NA",
    "windchill_string": "NA",
    "windchill_f": "NA",
    "windchill_c": "NA",
    "feelslike_string": "66.3 F (19.1 C)",
    "feelslike_f": "66.3",
    "feelslike_c": "19.1",
    "visibility_mi": "10.0",
    "visibility_km": "16.1",
    "solarradiation": "",
    "UV": "5",
    "precip_1hr_string": "0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
    "precip_1hr_in": "0.00",
    "precip_1hr_metric": " 0",
    "precip_today_string": "0.00 in (0 mm)",
    "precip_today_in": "0.00",
    "precip_today_metric": "0",
    "icon": "partlycloudy",
    "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
    "forecast_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html",
    "history_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KCASANFR58/2012/6/27/DailyHistory.html",
    "ob_url": "http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=37.773285,-122.417725"
}
```

}
Now how can I get `temp_c` value?

I did `NSLog(allData)` and `@"temp_c" : (double)26.9`
Could be I'm trying to store in `NSString` double value?

I tried changing value in current code to `allData[@"current_observation"]` and `weatherDictonary[@"temp_c"]`, but I get always an error.

Comment: Can you explain what you think that `for` loop is doing?

Comment: If you can paste here your whole JSON?

Comment: @trojanfoe I really have no idea, i you have a better way accessing it tell me please.

Comment: @Jack it's really important to see whole JSON object because this is array of dictionaries, and you need to iterate through that array and get value for key that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"current_observation" does not contain an Array, it contains Dictionary

```
NSDictionary* weather = allData[@"current_observation"];
NSString *currentWeather = nil;
NSString *currentTemp = nil;
if (weather[@"temperature_string"]){
    currentWeather = weather[@"temperature_string"];
}
if (weather[@"temp_c"]) {
    currentTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",weather[@"temp_c"]];
}
```

"temp_c" is a number and not string so you need to cast it to string.

Comment: Ooooh ok! Got it! Thanks alot for explanation!!

Comment: You can make it slightly simpler by doing `NSString *currentWeather = weather[@"temperature_string"];`, etc, with using `if`.  You get the same result.

Comment: Sure you can do it this way, but with using if statement you are doing it safe, especially if you are getting data from a third party.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really good explanation for your problem,in previous comment.You have a `NSDictionary` not an `NSArray`. Simply solution is to just iterate:

```
NSString *weather =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [allData objectForKeyPath:@"temp_c"]];
```